# how to change math.random() implemented in javascript to securerandom

Tags: random-number-generator

In Javscript code in one of our application,I am trying to change Math.random to secure random.I am not sure ,how to change.can anybody help?

Comment: Something like this perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19203948/1679849

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a programming problem rather than a cryptography question. If the link above doesn't help you could try asking on Stack Overflow.